# Best practices to limit the number of calls to Mirror API

Tags: google-mirror-api

I, like everyone else I imagine, have a courtesy limit of 1000 Mirror API calls per day.

I see there's a batching facility that looks promising, but it appears to be able to batch only requests for a single credential. So even one customer, pushing to the API every 60 seconds will be 1440 requests/day. Ideally, 30 seconds is where I'd like to be. 2880 requests/day would be multiplied by the number of customers. It will get really big really fast.

I might be missing something, but I don't see a way around that.

If it were available I could glom all updates across all clients in the 30 second period into one giant message...

Is there a better design pattern to keep cards up-to-date with telemetry that's changing in real-time?

Comment: Just a quick note that batching doesn't actually reduce the number of counted API requests, it only reduces the HTTP overhead. If you batch 10 requests together they will still be counted as 10 requests against the API quota.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send requests to multiple users with a single batch request: instead of setting the `Authorization` header in the batch request, simply set the `Authorization` header in each sub-request.

Our [Python](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-python) and [Java Quick Start](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-java) projects have an example of using batch request to send an update to up to 10 users. This is also mentioned in the [Building Glass Services with the Google Mirror API](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/332733833) I/O session.

Otherwise, you can check the protocol documentation in our [reference guide](https://developers.google.com/glass/batch).

As Scarygami mentioned, each sub-request will consume quota so the only optimization is to save on bandwidth and HTTP requests, especially if using `gzip` encoding.